# Styles missing in StreamWriter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I see that when I use `StreamWriter` to write html to excel file, it is missing some styles like background color. Is it possible to get styles using `StreamWriter`? If Not, Can I use any other `StreamWriter`?

```
StringWriter _writer = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("VAMReport.aspx", _writer);
String html = _writer.ToString();
fullpath = directoryPath + @"\" + fileName;
StreamWriter SW;            
SW = File.CreateText(fullpath);
SW.WriteLine(html.ToString());
SW.Close();
```

Comment: Whether you're using `StreamWriter` or another strategy to write your file is irrelevant here: the problem is that Excel either doesn't see or doesn't support the styles you're using in your markup. Can you post the relevant parts of that markup in your question? Also, you're not using an external stylesheet, right?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not using any external stylesheet. This is my aspx page, where I have defined the Styles in the html controls.

Comment: <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="div1" runat="server">  
    <p style="font-family:times;color:green; background:red;">
    <label id="lb1" runat="server">Appraisal Failure Details Report</label>
    <br />
    <label id="lb2" runat="server">Hard Stop Failures</label>
    <br />
    <label id="lb3" runat="server">Date of Report :02/01/2012 4:36</label>
    <label id="lb4" runat="server">Date Range of Report :12/16/2011 to 12/31/2011</label>
    </p>  
    </div>
    <div id="dataBindingDiv" runat="server" ></div>   
    
    </form>
</body>

Comment: Looks like Excel doesn't support the `background` and `background-color` style rules. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8092007/464709.

Answer (score 1):

`StreamWriter` just writes text. It has no concepts of style, font, or anything like that. It can include HTML of course, as that's just text - but how Excel deals with that is up to Excel.

As an aside, you should use a `using` statement for code where you *do* need to open a `StreamWriter`, but in this case you don't need to anyway - just use:

```
File.WriteAllText(fullPath, html);
```

If you need to write full-blown Excel files, you should look at other potential options - whether that's COM interop or potentially one of the many 3rd party libraries which allows you to create Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: I have tried to use COM Interop, but was facing two problems, one being the asp controls were not exported to excel and another being performance issue for huge records(around 50k)